# Using VBA to execute COM add-in specific formula

Tags: vba, thomson-reuters-eikon

I am trying to use a VBA macro to execute formulas in an excel sheet, which were added by an add-in. Specifically, the add-in is Thomson Reuter's Eikon and it provides functions starting with "=TR(....)".

My add-in works as follows: It puts together the formula starting with "=TR" as a string. Than I want to paste these strings into an excel sheet, so that they are executed seperately. When I do so, I always get runtime error 1004.

I tried to paste the formula using Cells().Formula, which works, if I try a standard excel formula. However, it does not work with the add-in specific formula.

Answer (score 1):

I found out, that "Cells(...).FormulaLocal" does the trick.